# PUG Template: Ignore undefined/null variables

Tags: express, pug

I have an Expressjs application which uses PUG as view template compiler. I am on a registration form page.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="input-field">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="!{req.email}">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
</div>
```

When browsing the route which renders the file, script crashes under the following error:

> Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Though I know `req.email` is undefined, I need it there to render the email address in case user inputs it and sends it through the form. How to ignore the error and keep the script execution going?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a ternary conditional to check if the `req` object exists and has an `email` property, and if not, render an empty `value` attribute:

```
input#email(
  type='email',
  name='email',
  value= (req && req.email) ? req.email : ''
)
```